# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation on Samsung Devices

Tags: android, galaxy

I'm getting this exception at random places in my app, and I've only seen crashes on various Samsung devices (Galaxy Note 2, Galaxy S2). My app relies on a few different library projects and I've verified that I'm not including jars twice, etc. I'm at a complete loss as to why this is happening since I've not received it on any of my 5+ test devices and have received very few crash reports, however a few certain lucky people can't use the app without it crashing.

Here are a couple stack traces:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected      implementation
    at com.tvshowfavs.services.api.ServerDataStoreService.onHandleIntent(ServerDataStoreService.java:93)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

And:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
at com.tvshowfavs.widget.AppWidgetPreferences.getTabs(AppWidgetPreferences.java:105)
at com.tvshowfavs.widget.AppWidgetConfigurationActivity.onTabsChanged(AppWidgetConfigurationActivity.java:337)
    at com.tvshowfavs.widget.AppWidgetConfigurationActivity.onCreate(AppWidgetConfigurationActivity.java:133)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:93)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone have any insight into these random crashes?

Comment: if you are using any library, that is belong to android library project, include library project instead of using jar directly

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so I figured out the issue. I'm using the Apache Commons Lang jar in the app and each place that it was crashing was on a call to StringUtils. The jar is only being added one time though, so I'm not sure why it was causing issues. However, removing the jar was the only way I could keep it from crashing on a user's Note 2. I wish I knew why it was crashing on his device because of this error though, since StringUtils is very handy :(